# How to select $r$ in Pedersen commitment scheme?

Tags: commitments, secp256k1

I'm implementing Pedersen commitment scheme in order to enhance entropy of a pre-image of a hash. I'm using secp256k1 for my curve parameters.

I am following naming conventions from here:
[What is a Pedersen commitment?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/64437/what-is-a-pedersen-commitment/64443#64443)

I am performing a commit $C = (m, r)$ and then another commit $C' = (m, r')$

Then I do the blind equality check $C - C' = (r - r')G.$

I got the blind equality check working, but only for some values of $r$. It looks like it works better when $r$ is a prime or when $r$ and $r'$ don't have common divisors.

What's the proper way to select $r$ values? Right now I am just selecting random values in between `0` and `0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffefffffc2f`

Comment: are you doing $r-r'\ mod\ q$?

Comment: Hmm, I'm doing `uint256 _r3 = submodP( _r1 , _r2 )`. I'm not sure what $q$ is, to be honest. Maybe `submodP` is not enough on its own and I do need to $mod  q$ on top of it. Thank you, I'll research that further.

Comment: For secp256k1, your group order $q$ is 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494337. You should not be doing mod p and mod q, only mod q.

Comment: Hi @knaccc you're right. Turns out I was doing `mod 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFFFC2F` and I had to just change it to `mod 0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364141` and it now works fine. That solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing `mod 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFFFC2F` for $(r - r')$ and I just had to change it to `mod 0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364141`. Not an issue with $r$ selection per se, but with computing $(r - r')$.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F3-540-46766-1_9.pdf#page=3), $r$ ($t$ in the paper) should be picked uniformly at random in $\mathbb{Z}_q$ (i.e $\big\{0, \dots, (q-1)\big\}$), with $q$ the order of $\mathbb{G}$.

According to [this link](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Secp256k1) the order is:

`FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFE BAAEDCE6 AF48A03B BFD25E8C D0364141`

Then you have to select a random value in between $0$ and

`FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFE BAAEDCE6 AF48A03B BFD25E8C D0364140` include.

Comment: That's a great paper, I'll research that further and figure out what I'm missing, thank you!